# Is there an explicit/crude saying for bravery in Chinese?

Tags: simplified-characters, idioms, old-chinese

I am looking for something similar to the english 'having big balls' as an indication of bravery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of one's 胆 (gallbladder) is metaphorically an indicator of courage, 胆大 = brave; 胆小 = cowardly

- 有种   (have pedigree) --> having great pride --> brave

Example sentence:

有种你别跑!  - if you have pride (dare), don't run

有种你别再追!  - if you have pride (dare), stop chasing me

- [斗胆](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E6%96%97%E8%86%BD): (gallbladder as big as a 斗): bold; brazen
- 吃了豹子胆  (ate leopard gallbladder) = brave; bold; brazen
- 胆大包天 / 胆包天 (brave enough to take on the world) = brave; bold; brazen

Cantonese:

- 胆生毛  (gallbladder grows hair) It is so big and manly, it grows hair
- 沙胆 (sandy gallbladder)  sandy-> rough -->tough = brave
- 胆粗 (gallbladder is thick): brave; 胆粗粗咁 (adv): bravely
- 够姜 (enough ginger = has a lot of spice): brave --> dare to do things plain people don't dare to do
- 敢死/ 夠胆死 (dare to die/ courageous enough to die) = "damn dare" as in "乜都夠胆死" (damn dare to do anything)

Comment: 有膽 can also go as "have the guts".

Comment: 膽生毛 is also purely Canto.

Comment: Also 胆肥 (fat gallbladder) means the same

Comment: I am not familiar with Bio, but isn't that "gall" means 胆汁 and 胆 is the "gallbladder"? I guess it is better to say "gallbladder".

Comment: “胆儿够肥啊！” suitable too